# Error when creating mongodb user in kubernetes environment

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

I am trying to create a mongodb user along with a stateful set. Here is my .yaml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 name: mongo
 labels:
  name: mongo
spec:
 type: NodePort
 ports:
  - port: 27017
    targetPort: 27017
 selector:
  name: mongo
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: admin-secret
  # corresponds to user.spec.passwordSecretKeyRef.name
type: Opaque
stringData:
  password: pass1
  # corresponds to user.spec.passwordSecretKeyRef.key
---
apiVersion: mongodb.com/v1
kind: MongoDBUser
metadata:
  name: admin
spec:
  passwordSecretKeyRef:
    name: admin-secret
    # Match to metadata.name of the User Secret
    key: password
  username: admin
  db: "admin" #
  mongodbResourceRef:
    name: mongo
    # Match to MongoDB resource using authenticaiton
  roles:
    - db: "admin"
      name: "clusterAdmin"
    - db: "admin"
      name: "userAdminAnyDatabase"
    - db: "admin"
      name: "readWrite"
    - db: "admin"
      name: "userAdminAnyDatabase"
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mongo
spec:
  serviceName: "mongo"
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: mongo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: mongo
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
      # - envFrom:
      #   - secretRef:
      #       name: mongo-secret
      - image: mongo
        name: mongodb
        command:
          - mongod
          - "--replSet"
          - rs0
          - "--bind_ip" 
          - 0.0.0.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
```

Earlier I used the secret to create a mongo user:

```
...
spec:
  containers:
  - envFrom:
    - secretRef:
      name: mongo-secret
...
```

but once I added spec.template.spec.containers.command to the StatefulSet this approach is no longer working. Then I added Secret and MongoDBUser but I started getting this error:

```
unable to recognize "mongo.yaml": no matches for kind "MongoDBUser" in version "mongodb.com/v1"
```

How to automatically create a mongodb user when creating StatefulSet with few replicas in kubernetes?

Comment: You encountered that error because you don't have the CustomResourceDefinition (CRD) for MongoDBUser. Which guide did you refer to create the YAML objects? Is your lone requirement to create MongoDB with a user, you can refer to this manifest: https://gist.github.com/thilinapiy/0c5abc2c0c28efe1bbe2165b0d8dc115 & https://medium.com/@dilipkumar/standalone-mongodb-on-kubernetes-cluster-19e7b5896b27

Comment: @hdhruna I refered the official documentation when I was creating a yaml file: https://docs.mongodb.com/kubernetes-operator/master/tutorial/manage-database-users-scram/ . My first version of the yaml without Secret and MongoDBUser used the env varibles to initialize mongo user - the similar approach to the medium post. I'll take a closer look to the gist, ty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the resources in your yaml file refers to a `kind` that doesn't exist in your cluster.

You can check this by running the command `kubectl api-resources | grep mongo -i`

Specifically it's the resource of kind `MongoDBUser`. This API resource type is part of [MongoDB Enterprise Kubernetes Operator](https://www.mongodb.com/kubernetes).

You haven't indicated whether you are using this in your cluster, but the error you're getting implies the CRD's for the operator are not installed and so cannot be used.

MongoDB Kubernetes Operator is a paid enterprise package for Kubernetes. If you don't have access to this enterprise package from MongoDB you can also install the community edition yourself by either setting up all the resources yourself or using [Helm](https://helm.sh/) to install it as a package. Using Helm makes managing the resources significantly easier, especially with regards to configuration, upgrades, re-installation or unistalling. The existing Helm charts are open source and also allow for running MongDB as a standalone instance, replica set or a sharded cluster.

For reference, Bitnami [provides a MongoDB Standalone or replica set helm chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/mongodb) which seems to be on the latest MongoDB version and is maintained regularly. There is also [this one](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/mongodb-replicaset), but it's on an older version of MongoDB and doesn't seem to be getting much attention.

Comment: so I am trying to use Bitnami's helm chart but it won't create replicas for me. When I call helm install ... the first replica stuck in a pending state. So does the pvc. I created local PersistentVolume and StorageClass resources but the problem still remains. Is that the issue in the chart or I missed some prerequisite?

Comment: You'll need to inspect the values of that helm chart that can be set. Most notably they have a values-production.yaml file which by default enables K8s stateful set as a MongoDB replica set. It's just enabling properties. I can remember if persistence is enabled by default, if not just set `persistence.enabled` to true. If enabled, it will automatically create the PVC's and PV's, and if running in a cloud platform, this will also create the physical disk. If it's not starting up, look at the k8s events and inspect the pod status, events and logs. Likely it's not finding your PVC's.

Comment: Here's an example command to install the chart where the chart has been download. 

`helm install --name my-mongodb-install --namespace db -f mongodb-bitnami/values-production.yaml -f my-custom-overrides.yaml --set persistence.size="8Gi" --set mongodbRootPassword=changeit ./mongodb-bitnami`

Comment: Just a warning, if you intend to access the MongoDB server from outside the cluster you will have some problems. It's possible by using nginx-ingress and enabling udp traffic going into the cluster on port 27017. But for a replica set this is really complicated as the DNS names for each node in the MongoDB set are assigned at install time and are only resolvable from within the cluster.

Comment: Update previous comment above: The latest version of Bitnami's MongoDB Helm chart has changed quite a lot and solved the external access issues. Works really well now.